# float right not working in media queries?

Tags: html, css

It seems to be float not working while using media queries..

Here the HTML:

```
<div id="mpass">
<span onclick="fpass()"><a href="#" class="fpassword">forgot Password?</a></span>
<p class="change_link">Not a member yet?<a onclick="empty()" href="#toregister" class="to_register">Join us</a></p></div>
```

forget password doesnt aligining right,

Here is the css:

```
.fpassword { font-size: 90%; white-space: nowrap; display: inline-table; float: right!important; padding: 0 0 0 0; top: 60%; margin: 10% 0 0 0;}
#mpass { float: right!important; display: inline-table;}
```

Please advice me to align "forgot password?" to the right of the page???

Comment: just add # before mpass in your css

Comment: is _mpass { .. }_ unfinished? If it's not, you could be missing a class or id identifier (. # etc.)

Comment: Sorry, i missed out # to mentioned in mpass, its not working still..., please advice??

Comment: could you please create a jsFiddle demo for us so we've got something to look at? Sounds like there could be other things at play affecting the float.

Answer (score 0):

Add `#` to `mpass { ... }`

example:

`#mpass { float: right!important; display: inline-table;}`

Comment: I have used this "#mpass { float: right!important; display: inline-table;}" as you mentioned, but still its not working !, please help me on this...

Comment: @Karim AG: 
Could you give me your mail ID, so that i can mail you the complete code for your reference???

Comment: Could you give me your mail ID, so that i can mail you the complete code for your reference???